# RStudio/Sparklyr on MAPR/Spark - Replace , to . in string

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

I'm having a Spark dataframe tbl_pred with the folowing factor column:

```
**Value**    
13,3
11
5,3
```

I like to convert those 'strings' to numeric values. I can use the as.numeric function, but this doesn't work because my seperator is a comma.

```
tbl_pred <- tbl_bun %>% mutate(value = as.numeric(value))
```

Normally I would use the sub function to replace the , to a . but this function does not work on my Spark dataframe object.

```
Error: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Undefined function: 'SUB'. This function is neither a registered temporary function nor a permanent function registered in the database 'xxx'.; line 1 pos 417
```

Does someone have a solution for converting the values to a numeric?

Thanks in advance,

J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`regexp_replace` is the function you need here:

```
tbl_bun %>% mutate(value=as.numeric(regexp_replace(value, ",", "\\.")))
```

When in doubt see [Hive Language Manual UDF](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF). Pretty much every function there either has native Spark implementation or is exposed as a Hive UDF.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I needed.